# Next.js Image Component Error: "Image is missing required 'src' property"

Tags: image, next.js, strapi

**Strapi v4.11.5 and Next.js 13.4.19**

I'm encountering an issue while trying to fetch images in a Next.js project. I have a component that uses the Image component from Next.js to display images fetched from an API. However, I'm consistently receiving  "Image is missing required 'src' property" when attempting to load the images.

```
"use client"

import React from 'react';
import useFetch from '@hooks/usefetch';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import '@styles/globals.css';
import TopBanner from '@components/TopBanner';
import Nav from '@components/Nav';
import Search from '@components/Search';
import Footer from '@components/Footer';
import { FaRegBookmark, FaMapMarkerAlt } from 'react-icons/fa';
import qs from 'qs';

const vendors = () => {

const queryParams = {
  fields: [
    'Name',
    'About',
    'Images.url',
    'Review.Rating',
    'Services.Name',
    'Location.Street',
    'Location.City',
    'Logo.url',
  ],
  populate: {
    Images: {
      fields: ['url'],
    },
    Review: {
      fields: ['Rating'],
    },
    Services: {
      fields: ['Name'],
    },
    Location: {
      fields: ['Street', 'City'],
    },
    Logo: {
      fields: ['url'],
    },
  },
};

const queryString = qs.stringify(queryParams, { indices: false });

const apiUrl = `http://localhost:1044/api/vendors?${queryString}`;

const { loading, error, data } = useFetch(apiUrl);

  if (loading) return <div className='loading-center'><div className='building-blocks'><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div></div>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  return (
    <div>
      <TopBanner />
      <Nav />
      <div className="w-full flex-center flex-col max-w-screen-lg">
      <Search />
        {data.data.map((vendor) => (
          <div key={vendor.id} className="vendor-card bg-[#f4f4f4] rounded-lg p-10 m-20 mt-10 mb-4 w-1/2">
            <div className="flex">
              <div className="w-1/6">
                <Image
                  src={vendor.attributes.Logo.url}
                  alt="Vendor Logo"
                  width={70}
                  height={70}
                  className="object-contain rounded-lg"
                />

              </div>
              <div className="w-3/4">
                <h2>{vendor.attributes.Name}</h2>
                <small className="flex items-center">
                <FaRegBookmark className="mr-2" /><strong>{vendor.attributes.Review.Rating} Saves</strong></small>
                <small className="flex items-center">
                  <FaMapMarkerAlt className="mr-2" />
                  <a
                    href={`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${encodeURIComponent(vendor.attributes.Location.Street + ', ' + vendor.attributes.Location.City)}`}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  >
                    {vendor.attributes.Location.Street}, {vendor.attributes.Location.City}
                  </a>
                </small>
                <div className="mt-2">
                <small>
                <p><strong>Services</strong></p>{' '}
                  {vendor.attributes.Services.map((service, index) => (
                    <span key={service.id}>
                      {service.Name}
                      {index !== vendor.attributes.Services.length - 1 ? ' • ' : ''}
                    </span>
                  ))}
                </small>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="w-1/6 flex justify-end">
                <Link href={`/vendor/${vendor.id}`}>
                  <button className="purple_btn">View</button>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default vendors;
```

Here's what I've done so far:

I've verified the constructed image URLs, and they seem correct, including the full path to the images on the server.
The API response contains the expected image URLs, and the data structure seems correct.
I've checked the server logs, but I couldn't find any specific error messages related to this issue.
I've followed the guidance from the Next.js documentation and added the required configuration in next.config.js to include the hostname "localhost" in the images property.

Despite these steps, I'm still encountering the error. Could there be any other factors causing this  "Image is missing required 'src' property" when trying to load images in my Next.js project? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried various approaches since posting this question. I thought the issue might be related to the way the image URL is being constructed or handled by the Image component. After analysing the code and responses, I implemented a slightly modified approach to ensure that the logo URL is accessed correctly. Here's the relevant part of the code:

````
      <div className="w-1/6">
    {console.log('Logo URL:', 'http://localhost:1044' + vendor.attributes.Logo.data.url)}
    {vendor.attributes.Logo && vendor.attributes.Logo.data && vendor.attributes.Logo.data.url ? (
      <Image
        src={'http://localhost:1044' + vendor.attributes.Logo.data.url}
        alt="Vendor Logo"
        width={70}
        height={70}
        className="object-contain rounded-lg"
      />
    ) : (
      <Image
        src="/images/logo-placeholder.png"
        alt="Placeholder Logo"
        width={70}
        height={70}
        className="object-contain"
      />
    )}
  </div>```
````

After implementing this approach, the error was fixed. However, even though the error was resolved, the image still didn't appear. The logged output was: Logo URL: http://localhost:1044undefined.

Here are all the vendor data attributes provided in the response for reference:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 3,
        "attributes": {
            "Email": "a@b.com",
            "createdAt": "2023-08-19T16:13:39.407Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-08-19T17:40:40.101Z",
            "publishedAt": "2023-08-19T16:13:43.266Z",
            "Name": "A vendor",
            "About": "Lorem ipsum",
            "Images": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "attributes": {
                            "name": "Awards-Banner-1560x500-1.jpg",
                            "alternativeText": null,
                            "caption": null,
                            "width": 1560,
                            "height": 500,
                            "formats": {
                                "thumbnail": {
                                    "name": "thumbnail_Awards-Banner-1560x500-1.jpg",
                                    "hash": "thumbnail_Awards_Banner_1560x500_1_b15a6c7c84",
                                    "ext": ".jpg",
                                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                    "path": null,
                                    "width": 245,
                                    "height": 79,
                                    "size": 5.62,
                                    "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_Awards_Banner_1560x500_1_b15a6c7c84.jpg"
                                },
                                "medium": {
                                    "name": "medium_Awards-Banner-1560x500-1.jpg",
                                    "hash": "medium_Awards_Banner_1560x500_1_b15a6c7c84",
                                    "ext": ".jpg",
                                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                    "path": null,
                                    "width": 750,
                                    "height": 240,
                                    "size": 34.73,
                                    "url": "/uploads/medium_Awards_Banner_1560x500_1_b15a6c7c84.jpg"
                                },
                                "small": {
                                    "name": "small_Awards-Banner-1560x500-1.jpg",
                                    "hash": "small_Awards_Banner_1560x500_1_b15a6c7c84",
                                    "ext": ".jpg",
                                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                    "path": null,
                                    "width": 500,
                                    "height": 160,
                                    "size": 17.77,
                                    "url": "/uploads/small_Awards_Banner_1560x500_1_b15a6c7c84.jpg"
                                },
                                "large": {
                                    "name": "large_Awards-Banner-1560x500-1.jpg",
                                    "hash": "large_Awards_Banner_1560x500_1_b15a6c7c84",
                                    "ext": ".jpg",
                                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                    "path": null,
                                    "width": 1000,
                                    "height": 321,
                                    "size": 55.01,
                                    "url": "/uploads/large_Awards_Banner_1560x500_1_b15a6c7c84.jpg"
                                }
                            },
                            "hash": "Awards_Banner_1560x500_1_b15a6c7c84",
                            "ext": ".jpg",
                            "mime": "image/jpeg",
                            "size": 104.1,
                            "url": "/uploads/Awards_Banner_1560x500_1_b15a6c7c84.jpg",
                            "previewUrl": null,
                            "provider": "local",
                            "provider_metadata": null,
                            "createdAt": "2023-07-19T16:04:54.998Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2023-07-19T16:04:54.998Z"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Review": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "Title": "Amazing",
                    "Body": "So goood",
                    "Rating": 5
                }
            ],
            "Services": [
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "Name": "A",
                    "Description": "B",
                    "Price": 1
                }
            ],
            "Location": {
                "id": 3,
                "Street": "A",
                "City": "B",
                "Country": "C"
            },
            "Logo": {
                "data": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "attributes": {
                        "name": "logo.png",
                        "alternativeText": null,
                        "caption": null,
                        "width": 294,
                        "height": 83,
                        "formats": {
                            "thumbnail": {
                                "name": "thumbnail_logo.png",
                                "hash": "thumbnail_logo_d4ec403db5",
                                "ext": ".png",
                                "mime": "image/png",
                                "path": null,
                                "width": 245,
                                "height": 69,
                                "size": 9.55,
                                "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_logo_d4ec403db5.png"
                            }
                        },
                        "hash": "logo_d4ec403db5",
                        "ext": ".png",
                        "mime": "image/png",
                        "size": 2.5,
                        "url": "/uploads/logo_d4ec403db5.png",
                        "previewUrl": null,
                        "provider": "local",
                        "provider_metadata": null,
                        "createdAt": "2023-07-19T16:04:35.184Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2023-07-19T16:04:35.184Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "meta": {}
}
```

I'm still investigating the issue and seeking further guidance to ensure that the logo image is correctly displayed. Thanks for your help in advance.

**2nd UPDATE**

Thanks to Robin's observation (REFFER TO COMMENTS), I was able to log and confirm the image URL. Despite this, I'm still encountering an issue where the image doesn't display on the frontend. **The error I have now is:** image:1     GET http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=%2Fuploads%2Fgladys_logo_b640cf71e2.png&w=256&q=75 400 (Bad Request)

Seeing this I thought it could be a CORS issue.

Steps Taken:

- Verified Image URLs ensuring that the image URLs used in the frontend match the URLs accessible in the browser.
- Disabled browser extensions that might interfere with network requests.
- Restarted Servers
- Updated middlewares.js:

```
    module.exports = [
          'strapi::errors',
          'strapi::security',
          {
            name: 'strapi::cors',
            config: {
              origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:1044'], // Add both frontend and backend origins
            },
          },
          'strapi::poweredBy',
          'strapi::logger',
          'strapi::query',
          'strapi::body',
          'strapi::session',
          'strapi::favicon',
          'strapi::public',
        ];
```

- Attempted a number of different configurations in  next.config.js   / latest:

```
    const nextConfig = {
          images: {
            domains: ['http://localhost:1044'], // Add other domains if needed
            reactStrictMode: true,
            loader: 'default', // Specify the loader type if needed
            remotePatterns: [
              {
                protocol: 'http',
                hostname: 'localhost',
                port: '1044',
              },
            ],
          },
        };
        
        module.exports = nextConfig;
```

If you have any further insights or suggestions, your guidance would be much appreciated.

**Project structure**

[image: project structure]

Comment: When you console log this `vendor.attributes.Logo.url`, what do you get?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar thanks for taking a look, this error is logged: console.error @ client.js:1
window.console.error @ next-dev.js:27
eval @ image-component.js:174
commitAttachRef @ react-dom.development.js:23645
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23503
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender

Comment: Can you add that error to the question description? Hard to read from a comment.

Comment: Also, do share whats the value of `vendor.attributes` for all the vendors

Comment: @RobinThomas thanks for taking a look, I added an update to my question.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `'http://localhost:1044' + vendor.attributes.Logo.data.attributes.url`? Notice the `data.attributes`

Comment: @RobinThomas Thank you for pointing that out! You are absolutely right. I updated the code accordingly. As a result, I'm now able to confirm the image URL is being correctly logged: Logo URL: http://localhost:1044/uploads/logo_d4ec403db5.png. Despite this, I'm still encountering an issue where the image doesn't display on the frontend.

Comment: Can you check if you have an errors in the browser console?

Comment: Hello  @RobinThomas , yes sorry for the late reply, I added a 2nd update to my question. Thanks again for your ongoing support.

Comment: @AbdelDjeebet Can you share a screenshot of your `public` directory, showing the project structure, where your images are stored?

Comment: @RobinThomas sure I have added it, please check the question.

Comment: @AbdelDjeebet Your frontend is trying to download an image thats part of `backend` service? If thats the case, I'm assuming both are running in `localhost`. So are you using the correct `port` (of `backend` and not `frontend`) in the url to download the image?

Comment: Also what ports are `frontend` and `backend` services running on?

Comment: @RobinThomas yes that's correct frontend is trying to download an image from backend, both on localhost. The frontend is on http://localhost:3000, and the backend is on http://localhost:1044. I've made attempts with various configurations, including trying to directly append http://localhost:1044 before the image URL (which is where the image is stored) but what happens is that http://localhost:1044 gets concatenated with http://localhost:3000, resulting in a URL like this: http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1044%2Fuploads%2Fthumbnail_ruhee_f1bf3840b8.jpg&w=256&q=75

Comment: @AbdelDjeebet What if you replace the `<Image />` component by `<img>`? Does that work?

Comment: @RobinThomas you my friend are a legend! That's it! That solved the problem. To be honest, I'm not sure how long it would have taken me to figure that out on my own. Thanks a lot man, all the best.

Comment: @RobinThomas I tried mate but I don't have enough rep to cast a vote, I will come back to it when I do 

Comment: Yes! I have indeed! Upvoted ;) Thanks again and all the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error from Next.js means that `src` attribute supplied to the `<Image />` is `undefined`.

Given that your component is:

```
<Image
  src={vendor.attributes.Logo.url}
  alt="Vendor Logo"
  width={70}
  height={70}
  className="object-contain rounded-lg"
/>
```

Since you are supplying `vendor.attributes.Logo.url` as the `src`, that means `vendor.attributes.Logo.url` is `undefined`.

#### Update 1:

In your latest code, I can see that the `<Image />` component has been updated.

```
<Image
  src={'http://localhost:1044' + vendor.attributes.Logo.data.url}
  alt="Vendor Logo"
  width={70}
  height={70}
  className="object-contain rounded-lg"
/>
```

But `vendor.attributes.Logo.data.url` is also `undefined`. It's supposed to be `vendor.attributes.Logo.data.attributes.url` instead.